# Typescript: dynamically define a length of a returned tuple/array based on tuple/array function args

Tags: arrays, typescript, types, tuples

Consider the following typescript code:

```js
function concatTuples<T>(first: [...T[]], second: [...T[]]): [...T[]] {
  return [...first, ...second];
}

const result = concatTuples([0, 1], [2, 3]);
```

So the function joins tuples. Currently there is no way of knowing what the lenght of the returned tuple is.

**Current type of `result`:** `number[]`.

**What I'd like the type to be** : `[number, number, number, number]`.

So that the size of the returned tuple/array needs to be dynamically infered from function arguments.

Is there any way of achieving this? I looked around the docs and didn't find any straightforward solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not really using [tuple types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types) in your code; the `T` type parameter is just the element type, and the tuple type consisting of only [the rest element](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-0.html#rest-elements-in-tuple-types) `[...T[]]` is immediately reduced to the unordered and arbitrarily-long array type `T[]`.  Thus your code is just accepting two arrays of type `T[]` and returning another one.

To support your use case you want to use [variadic tuple types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-0.html#variadic-tuple-types), and will need two type parameters: one for each array type (and not their elements).  It looks like this:

```
function concatTuples<T extends any[], U extends any[]>(
  first: [...T], second: [...U]
): [...T, ...U] {
    return [...first, ...second];
}
```

And now things work as you intended:

```
const result = concatTuples([0, 1], [2, 3]);
// const result: [number, number, number, number]
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=8&ts=4.7.4#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABBBECGUAqIAOAbAUwGcAeTRAgDygLABMjE0wBPAbQF0AaRAVQuq0GTVpwB8ACmAwATkSgAuRGwB0azN0RECKektVreHAJT61KzD3NHEAbwBQiJ4hkEoIGUgMrpcqFbVtXToOAG57AF97e115F2IQPChEAF5kVAxsfGIJNgAGHgBGTTYAJh4AZhNwgHoa9LA41yJExWUwEABbACMCGR4Onr6Brt7+xEGxjiA)